# neo4j cypher aggregation performance help needed

Tags: performance, neo4j, cypher, aggregation

i have the following query (with dummy relation and labels names),
and the profiler shows my #of hit as 3 times as the count of the User nodes count.

```
MATCH (user:User) 
WHERE NOT(user-[:r1]->(:L1)) AND NOT(user-[:r2]->(:L2)) 
return count(user)
```

i wonder if there is a way to make it run faster

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use `size` which will produce the Java equivalent of `getDegree()` and is more performant.

```
MATCH (user:User)
WHERE size((user)-[:r1]->(:L1)) = 0
AND size((user)-[:r2]->(:L2)) = 0
return count(user)
```

If you compare the query plans, you can see that the plan with size is more linear :

WITH `WHERE NOT` :

[image]

WITH `size()` (getDegree)

[image]

Comment: sorry @Christophe, but the profiler shows even more db hits.
 im using version 2.3 m2 currently

Comment: I don't have profiled yet these kind of queries yet for 2.3 milestone releases. I'll check this out

Comment: @LiorGoldemberg - more dbhits doesn't meand that query is faster or slower. Checkout this article - http://neo4j.com/blog/neo4j-2-2-query-tuning/

Comment: True. But if there is a huge difference, this is something to narrow though

Comment: what is the size of the dataset ?